# Is there another way of finding the Average besides DAvg?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I inherited this access database at work and I am looking for a faster way to write some code. Currently it takes almost 1.5 minutes to run this and I am needing it to be much faster.

Currently I have it all set up as DAvg and DCount but the problem with this is that it basically opens and closes the query for each line that its used it. On its own its fine but I need to do this 36 times.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo errhndlr
    Me.Visible = True
    Dim FY_EngMiss, Prev_EngMiss, LThree_EngMiss, LNine_EngMiss, FY_DraftMiss, Prev_DraftMiss, LThree_DraftMiss, LNine_DraftMiss As Integer
    Dim FY_Eng, Prev_Eng, LThree_Eng, LNine_Eng, FY_Draft, Prev_Draft, LThree_Draft, LNine_Draft As Integer
    Dim FY_Fups, Prev_Fups, LThree_Fups, LNine_Fups, FY_pjs, Prev_Pjs, LThree_Pjs, LNine_Pjs, EngMissed As Integer
    Dim FY_Quote, Prev_Quote, LThree_Quote, LNine_Quote As Double
    Dim FY_Avg, Prev_AVG, LThree_Avg, LNine_Avg As Double
    Dim SummaryDate, FiscalDate, LThreeDate As Date
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Me.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
    Me.SummaryDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.SDate
    Me.FiscalDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.FiscalStartDate
    SummaryDate = CDate(DateValue(Me.SummaryDate))
    FiscalDate = CDate(DateValue(Me.FiscalDate))
    LThreeDate = CDate(DateValue(DateAdd("m", -1, Me.SummaryDate)))

    'Quality Metrics

    Me.JW_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.CD_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.FM_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.JP_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.MB_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.BE_DAYRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")

    Me.JW_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.CD_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.FM_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.JP_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.MB_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.BE_DAYQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE' and Format([CompletedDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "'")

    Me.JW_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.CD_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.FM_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.JP_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.MB_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.BE_MRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")

    Me.JW_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.CD_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.FM_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.JP_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.MB_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")
    Me.BE_MQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE' and [CompletedDate] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & LThreeDate & "#")

    Me.JW_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW'")
    Me.CD_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD'")
    Me.FM_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM'")
    Me.JP_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP'")
    Me.MB_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB'")
    Me.BE_YRNK = DAvg("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE'")

    Me.JW_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JW'")
    Me.CD_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'CD'")
    Me.FM_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'FM'")
    Me.JP_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'JP'")
    Me.MB_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'MB'")
    Me.BE_YQTY = DCount("AvgOfProjectRank", "Email_Ranking", "[Approver] = 'BE'")
Exit Sub
errhndlr:
    Call Errhndler.ErrorHandler(Err.Number, Err.Description, Me.Name, "Form_Load")
End Sub
```

Here is the SQL Text for the Email_Ranking Query as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
       archived_email.ProjectID, 
       archived_email.subject, 
       archived_email.approver, 
       archived_email.completeddate, 
       Avg(timestamp.projectrank) AS AvgOfProjectRank 
FROM   fy_current_external, 
       archived_email 
       INNER JOIN [timestamp] 
               ON archived_email.projectid = timestamp.projectid 
GROUP  BY archived_email.projectid, 
          archived_email.subject, 
          archived_email.approver, 
          archived_email.completeddate, 
          fy_current_external.date_value 
HAVING ( ( ( archived_email.approver ) = "mb" 
            OR ( archived_email.approver ) = "fm" 
            OR ( archived_email.approver ) = "jw" 
            OR ( archived_email.approver ) = "be" 
            OR ( archived_email.approver ) = "cd" 
            OR ( archived_email.approver ) = "jp" ) 
         AND ( ( archived_email.completeddate ) >= [date_value] ) 
         AND ( ( LEFT([archived_email]![projectid], 2) ) = "e-" 
                OR ( LEFT([archived_email]![projectid], 2) ) = "pl" ) ) 
ORDER  BY archived_email.completeddate DESC;
```

The query that it is searching is contains over 6,000 items.
The time to run this code is 88 seconds on average. This code is in multiple locations. I would like to reduce this time by at least half, preferably down to 10 seconds or less.

Comment: Not familiar with Access (I do know its SQL flavor is rather limited though), but couldn't you write a parameterized query that calculates these averages?

Comment: The query already contains parameters. Without creating a separate query for each of the 36 items I don't know how else to condense the query.

Comment: AFAICT you're using `DAvg` and `DCount` functions *outside* the query. On SQL Server I would use a windowing function to calculate the average/rank by approver, and perhaps even pivot the result so that I have `JW_DAYRNK`, `CD_DAYRNK`, ..., `JW_DAYQTY`, ..., `BE_DAYQTY` columns in the recordset - i.e. let the query to the calculations, not external functions. Not sure how that would be done in Access /without windowing functions though - I guess it involves a number of sub-queries... obviously not optimal. If your backend is SQL Server, make a T-SQL view or stored procedure for it.

Comment: A lot of that went over my head unfortunately. I am relatively new to coding VBA and have zero experience with SQL. I am guessing that the backend is not a SQL server but if it is, how would I check that?

Comment: If I understand this, the query basically groups on approver and filters on completion dates. Why can't you simply create a query that does `...WHERE CompletedDate = <some condition> GROUP BY Approver...`?

Comment: I think I have. Here is the query that it is reading. 

Field: Approver Table: Archived_Email Total: Group By Sort: Null Show: True Criteria: "MB" Or "FM" Or "JW" Or "BE" Or "CD" Or "JP"

Field: CompletedDate Table Archived_Email Total: Group By Sort: Descending Show: True Criteria: >=[Date_Value]

Comment: Switch `Email_Ranking` to SQL view, and add the full SQL text to your question, after running it through http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: As requested I have added the SQL text after format.

Comment: OK, that's the problem. You're doing too much. You need to split your queries up. You are doing both calculations and presentations in one big query which won't be right. instead, create a separate query that groups on ONLY the `Approver` with the completion date as the filter. Then join to another query that provides the output you want to display based on the approver. Odds are that you won't even need `DISTINCT` / `DISTINCTROW` once you set up the stacked queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
Dim SummaryDate As String
Dim FiscalDate As String
Dim LThreeDate As String
Dim Sql As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Me.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
Me.SummaryDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.SDate
Me.FiscalDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.FiscalStartDate
SummaryDate = Format(Me.SummaryDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
FiscalDate = Format(Me.FiscalDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
LThreeDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Me.SummaryDate.Value), "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

Sql = "Select Approver, Avg(AvgOfProjectRank) As PrjRnk, Count(*) As PrjQty " & _
      "From [Email_Ranking] " & _
      "Where DateValue([CompletedDate]) = #" & SummaryDate & "# " & _
      "Group By Approver"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)

' Loop the approvers and their controls.
While Not rst.EOF
    Me(rst!Approver.Value & "_DAYRNK").Value = rst!PrjRnk.Value
    Me(rst!Approver.Value & "_DAYQTY").Value = rst!PrjQty.Value
    rst.MoveNext
Wend
rst.Close
```

Comment: Kudos for also fixing the "average of averages" math!

Comment: I might have missed something. I tried your code and got the following error. "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Approver Where DateValue([CompletedDate]) = #2019/09/06#".

Where it highlights is the Set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(Sql)

Comment: Thank you! With that change it worked! With that change it took it from about 88 seconds down to about 20 seconds! Woooo! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [continuous](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-in-access-5d550a3d-92e1-4f38-9772-7e7e21e80c6b#createcontinuous) form with date control in the form header and use an aggregate query as the form's recordsource. Then, with any change of date parameter, simply run a `.Requery`:

**SQL** *(no concatenation, no punctuation, no recordsets, no date handling)*

```sql
SELECT [Approver], 
       AVG(IIF([CompletedDate] = Forms!myForm!SummaryDate, AvgOfProjectRank, NULL)) AS DAYRNK, 
       SUM(IIF([CompletedDate] = Forms!myForm!SummaryDate, 1, 0)) AS DAYQTY, 
       AVG(IIF([CompletedDate] BETWEEN Forms!myForm!SummaryDate + 1 
                                   AND DATEADD("m", -1, Forms!myForm!SummaryDate), 
               AvgOfProjectRank, NULL)) AS DAYMRNK,
       SUM(IIF([CompletedDate] BETWEEN Forms!myForm!SummaryDate + 1
                                   AND DATEADD("m", -1, Forms!myForm!SummaryDate), 
               1, 0)) AS MQTY, 
       AVG(AvgOfProjectRank) AS YRNK, 
       SUM(AvgOfProjectRank) AS YQTY
FROM Email_Ranking
WHERE [Approver] IN ('JW', 'CD', 'FM', 'JP', 'MB', 'BE')
GROUP BY [Approver];
```

**Form** *(only one textbox control)*

[image: form screenshot]

**VBA** *(one line of code to update form with every change of summary date)*

```
Private Sub SummaryDate_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Form.Requery
End Sub
```